# Div block not showing

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my otherEmailForm div to show however the verifyEmailForm shows up perfectly fine.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="verifyEmailForm">
            <h1 class="heading">Email verification</h1>
            <br/>
            <div class="content" id="content">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close"></i>
                <p id="msg">A verification code was sent to your email: <br><span class="emailText"></span></p>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <p>Code sent to <span class="emailText2"></span></p>
            </div>

            <div class="OTP">
                <input type="text" name="OTP" class="OTPcode" placeholder="Enter 6-digit code">
            </div>

            <div class="err">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"><span class="err_msg"></span></i>
            </div>

            <div class="resend space">
                <a class="resendOTP disabled">Resend code<span class="timer">(20)</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="submit space">
                <button class="submitOTP">Submit</button>
            </div>

            <div class="misc">
                <a>Use another email</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="otherEmailForm">
            <div>
                <button>TEST</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.otherEmailForm {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.container{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    clear: both;
}
```

I've tried everything to the best of my abilities yet I can seem to get a grip and tried searching the web about this for a while and I still can't seem to fix this probem.

Anyone know a possible solution to this?

Comment: Your `otherEmailForm` seems to be showing : https://jsfiddle.net/gqd1fs5k/

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your issue. The div with class of 'otherEmailForm' is being shown on the page. Maybe the only problem is that the height is set to 400px, which overflows the '.container', to solve that just set the width to 400px instead of the height.

```
`.otherEmailForm {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }`

`.otherEmailForm div {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
 }`
```

Maybe this changes can help you.

Some explanations:
width: 100% - sets the width of '.otherEmailForm' div to 100% of the '.container' width.

width: 70% - sets the width of the div inside of '.otherEmailForm' to 70% of the width of '.otherEmailForm'.

margin: auto - centers the div, adding the same amount of margin on the left and on the right of the div.

text-align: left - aligns the div text to the left.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions that are not reproduceable.  Your are guessing at what the original author is actually after or what the problem actually is. Please wait for clarification from the author.